# Adding mail addresses after each loop

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader

Currently when my program reads the specific table and sends Emails out to 8 users if there is 8 users there should receive one email. 
It should only send one email out per user. 
Not 8 emails per user. 
This is my code:

```
        comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblRent WHERE DateIn < " + ImorgenTicks + " AND Status = 'Out' AND Trainee IS NULL";

        SqlDataReader read = comm.ExecuteReader();
        if (read.HasRows)
        {
            while (read.Read())
            {
                string mail = read["Mail"].ToString();
                try
                {
                     message.To.Add(mail);
                    //email
                    smtp.Send(message);
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Text");
                } 

            } 
        }
```

I've searched the internet and found some solution and haven't got them to work.

Comment: Where did you create the message?

Comment: Why 8 mails per user? I  only see one loop on every record returned. If that's the table, you create one mail per user. If you only want to send one move the send-mail code out of the loop.

Comment: See solution.
This wasn't a duplicate since I was looking the wrong place. It was the message.to.clear() I was missing :-\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are adding multiple addresses to the same `MailMessage` on each iteration. You need to clear the `message.To` collection or create a new message in each iteration

```
while (read.Read())
{
    string mail = read["Mail"].ToString();
    try
    {
        message.To.Clear();
        message.To.Add(mail);

        //email    
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Text");
    } 
}
```